# how to subtract db time from real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, twilio, logic

I have this:

```
let minute = timeSplit[0];
let today = new Date();
if (Math.abs(today.getMinutes() - Number(minute)) <= 5) {
  client.messages.create(
    {
      to: userPhoneNumber,
      from: "12055578708",
      body:
        "hello " +
        userNameString +
        ", \nYour training session just finished with " +
        trainerNameString
    },
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err: " + err);
      }
      console.log(data);
    }
  );
} else {
  console.log("not working");
}
```

what it does is gets the current minute (ex. 54th minute of the hour), and subtract it from the `minute` that is in my database. If my db minute is within 5 minutes of the current minute, then do the next part.

However, in my db is both `minute` and `hour`. i need to check if the time in my db is within 5 minutes of the current time. `minute` and `hour` are both just string values. How can i do this?

Comment: It looks like that is what you are doing in your code. What is going wrong?

Comment: @philnash what it is doing right now is taking the minute in my db (Ex. 05), and the current minute, (57), and checking, is 57 - 05 <= 5. if it is, send text. if not, don't. so if the difference between the minutes is 5, then send. problem is, it is not checking for the hour as well. so if hour in db is 9, and hour now is 18, then it'll still send if its within the 5 MINUTE difference because i'm not checking for the hour. does that make more sense?

Comment: Right, so you need to check the hours too. What have you tried?

Comment: @philnash i've tried this `if (Math.abs(Number(currentHour)+":"+Number(currentMinute) - Number(myTime)) <= 5) {` ... my time it like `20:15`. and currentHour and currentMinute are variables that hold the javascript function `.getHour` and `.getMinute`... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the hour and the minute and you need to check whether that is within 5 minutes of the current time.

What you can do is build a date object for the same day, but using the time you have stored. So, if you have your minute and hour you want to compare, then you can do this:

```js
const today = new Date();
const myTime = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDay(), hour, minute);
```

Now you have two date objects that you can compare. When you subtract one from the other, the result will be in milliseconds, so you need to do some work to convert that to minutes. In this case we divide by 1000 to get seconds and then divide by 60 to get minutes. Then you apply the absolute function and check if it is less than 5.

```js
const difference = Math.abs((today - myTime) / 1000 / 60);
if (difference <= 5) {
  // send message
} else {
  // don't send the message now
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you for this. I couldn't figure this out for the life of me. Thank you for your help, you're a life saver.